# Application that use storyboard can deploy on iOS earlier than 5.0

Tags: ios, storyboard

The storyboard is a very powerful and easier way to build iOS apps. But I just want to know if apps made using them will work on iOS earlier than 5.0

Comment: With iOS 7 coming in about two to three months and over 90% of users using current latest version of the OS, you would probably be better off focusing on something other than supporting legacy OS versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nope, storyboards were only introduced in 5.0

Comment: thanks for your answer but let me know how to deploy application prior to iOS 5. Should i use xib for user interface or there is a way that i can still use storyboard in my app.

Comment: im afraid you will have to do it all in .xib files, that is the way it was done before using storyboards (or you can be hardcore and do it all in code.. :P)